# Changing an other Object's script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to change an other object's vitesse on collision, this is my code :

```
void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
{
    Collider collider = hit.collider;
    if (!collider.gameObject.name.Equals ("Plane"))
    {
        CharacterController opponent = collider.GetComponent(typeof(CharacterController)) as CharacterController;
        if (opponent  == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Vector3 pushDir = new Vector3(hit.moveDirection.x, 0, hit.moveDirection.z);
        opponent.Move (pushDir * pushPower * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

but that's not exacty what i want, actually, the opponent has also a script on it, and i want to change some attributes on the script, for exemple :

```
opponent.vitesse += pushDir * pushPower * Time.deltaTime;
```

vitesse is one of the attributes of the class Opponent on the objet opponent.
what i want is to change the vitesse of the opponent when i hit it instead of moving it directly

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. Is `vitesse` a public attribute? What error are you getting?

Comment: Yes vitesse is public, i'm not getting any errors, I just want to change the vitesse of the opponent when i hit it instead of moving it directly

Comment: So what is wrong with your example code?

Comment: in my example code i'm using the CharacterController directly to move the Object, I don't want to that, because i have a script that controls the position of the object, so i want to communicate with that script by changing the value of the speed.

Comment: oh. `vitesse` is French for speed. I see. I meant what is wrong with using your example code `opponent.vitesse += pushDir * pushPower * Time.deltaTime;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Opponent opponent = collider.GetComponent(typeof(Opponent)) as Opponent;
```

Instead of

```
CharacterController opponent = collider.GetComponent(typeof(CharacterController)) as CharacterController;
```

That way you can change the variables on your Opponent script

Full code:

```
void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
{
    Collider collider = hit.collider;
    if (!collider.gameObject.name.Equals ("Plane"))
    {
        Opponent opponent = collider.GetComponent(typeof(Opponent)) as Opponent;
        if (opponent  == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        opponent.vitesse += pushDir * pushPower * Time.deltaTime;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Niiice, I didn't know I could get the object opponent, that makes everything easier.

Comment: collider is a script attached to a gameobject, with GetComponent you can get any script attached to that gameobject. GetComponent is actually run on the gameobject so this would be the same as collider.gameObject.GetComponent...
I would also recommend using the generic version like this: 
Opponent opponent = collider.GetComponent<Opponent>(); since its nicer and you avoid the cast.